# MySQL query takes 10X time every once in a while

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, innodb, cpu-usage

I am working on this issue where a MySQL 'SELECT' query which usually completes in 2 minutes, but takes more than 25 minutes every once in a while (once in ten executions).
Could this be a:

1: Index issue - If this were, then the query would take equivalent time for every execution

2: Resource crunch - The CPU utilization did go up near 60-70% when this query gets stuck (this is usually around 40%)

3: Table lock issue - The logs say that the table was only locked for 10 ms. I do not know how to check for this.

Please suggest which issue appears most likely.

Thanks in advance...

Edit: Required information
Total rows: 40,000,000
Can't post the query or the schema (Will get fired)

Anyway, I just wanted to know the general analysis techniques.

Comment: mention total records in table?

Comment: Can you post the sql query and the table schema?

Comment: You'll have to provide some information about your database, such as create table, sample data, etc... and more importantly, the query

Comment: You can post the `CREATE TABLE` if you obfuscate the table and column names.  Also need enough of the `SELECT` to see most of the structure, again with obfuscated names.  You have not even provided us with the `ENGINE` -- if you are using MyISAM, then that could be a big factor.  Also need `EXPLAIN SELECT`.

Comment: Which log says 10ms?